# A Moose role of roles

Tags: perl, roles, moose

I'd like to set up a convenience Moose role made up of other smaller roles.  For example, if I have WithAddress and WithPhone I would like a single WithContacts that provides both WithAddress and WithPhone and anything contact methods I add in the future.

How can I do this with Moose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
package WithContacts;

use Moose::Role;
with qw(WithAddress WithPhone);

# anything else your role should do

no Moose::Role;
1;
```

Comment: *Ker-DUH!*  Does the `no Moose::Role` go after all the methods are defined?

Comment: @Schwern, normally you put `no Moose` or `no Moose::Role` immediately before the end of the file.  I think you can put it anywhere after you're done with `with` and `has` and `requires`, etc., but end-of-file is simplest.

Comment: It's not really needed at all; it just unimports the various sugar like 'has', 'with' etc. `use namespace::autoclean;` is arguably better (a best-practice on this isn't really figured out yet though).

Comment: If you're afraid of magic, and you're not using anything that imports functions *besides* Moose[::Role], then letting Moose do the unimport seems perfectly sensible. namespace::autoclean shines more when there's a big mess to clean up :)

Answer (score 0):

The new hotness is `use namepace::autoclean;` instead of `no Moose;` and `no Moose::Role;`.

In case you wanted to hear from more cjs :-)